# Python - Atribuir o valor de uma entry a uma váriavel

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis

Tentei usar o comando `mensagem = str(entry.get())` porém não funciona, tentei usar o `entry = Entry(root, textvariable='mensagem')` mas também não funciona, vejam o código inteiro basicamente quero digitar algo em uma entry e printar no console..

```
from tkinter import *
mensagem = str
def enviar():
    mensagem = str(entry.get())
    print(mensagem)

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root, textvariable=mensagem).place(x=10, y=10)
button = Button(root, text='ENVIAR', command=enviar).place(x=30, y=40)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def enviar():
    texto = mensagem.get()
    print(texto)
```

Quando você usa uma variável associada a uma Entry, deve fazer as chamadas a `get`  e `set` para a variável.
kinter ("mensagem") como o nome de uma variável local dentro da função, a primeira não estava visível para o Python - você teria o erro de que estava tentando acessar a variável local antes de atribui-la.

É só usar o nome global "mensagem" de forma  a não ter colisões com a variável local.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

mensagem = str

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()


def enviar():
    mensagem = str(entry.get())
    print(mensagem)


button = Button(root, text='ENVIAR', command=enviar)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Basta adicionar o .pack() e inicializar o entry antes de função, para o python conseguir acessar essa variável

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm